# REGEX: Extract parameter from URL

Tags: regex

What REGEX should I use to extract the following parameter from a url string:

```
/?c=135&a=1341
```

I basically want to get the value of the `a` parameter from this string.

Thanks,

Comment: There are two parameters in this url. Which one do you want?

Comment: As pointed out in my question, I am looking to extract the `a` value. I have already solved it.. see answer form `bunting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the value of a, and the value consists of one to many digits, this regex should work:

```
preg_match("/a=(\\d{1,})/ui", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)
```

Then use `$matches[1]` to display the `a` value

Comment: I wasnt able to get this working but I was able to find the following solution: `preg_match("/\?c=(\w+)\&a=(\w+)/i", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);` Thanks for helping...

Comment: Sure, with PHP the above would be: preg_match("/a=(\\d{1,})/ui", $searchText)

Comment: PERFECT. This works. Yeah, I should have pointed that out before that I was using PHP. Everything works good now... t

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer a slightly more general Q which is suggested by your ? prefix that you are trying to remove a specific parameter from a URI request string (which drops the leading ?). And in this case using the mod_rewrite engine so that you can implement this in your .htaccess file.

The rule is somewhat more complex because you don't necessarily know where in the query parameters a=XXX comes, so you need different regexps for the case where a is first and a is a subsequent parameter. You do this by `((?=a=)regexp1|regexp2)` so here it is:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase   \
 RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?(?=a=)a=[^&]*&?(.*)|(.*)&a=[^&]*(&.*)?)
 RewriteRule   ^.*             $0?%1%2%3                        [L]
```

If a is first the %1 contain rest otherwise %2 and %3 the bookends (%3 may be blank).

If you want this to occur for specific scripts then replace the rule regexp `^.*` by a more specific one.

Enjoy :-)

Comment: The same regexp will work in a `preg_match()` but why aren't you just using `$_GET` ???

Comment: I tried the stay away from .htaccess. I tried that before but did not work... maybe something is wrong with my system. I will check...

Comment: I note that you still ducked my Q as to why to are editing $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and not just using `$_GET` :-)

Comment: I am not sure how to use `_GET` in this situation. Can you suggest something for my learning. Thanks

Comment: Sure if you want to ignore a variable then just don't use it or unset it -- or are you calling some 3rd-part framework that accesses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] `